# Azure Timer Trigger Java Function returns 400 Bad Request while triggering manually

Tags: azure, azure-functions, timer-trigger

I created a Timer Trigger Azure Function in Java. Sometimes we need to manually execute that function as well. I am following the documentation and try to trigger the function via HTTP endpoint (`https://hostname/admin/functions/function name`) . But it is returning 400 Bad Request always. My function has no input .
I have tried with different POST Body like `{}` `{ "input": null }` and `{ "input": test}`.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced by creating a Time trigger function in VS code and deployed to the function app in Azure portal.

I copied the URL from function app and tried to post body in Postman with the same input you have given:

**Output:**
[image]

The body should be in **Json format** as below:

[image]